# Feedback topology of a common emitter circuit

Tags: feedback, common-emitter, topology

I was studying the topology of this particular circuit.

[image]

I do not understand how the topology of this circuit is considered series-series. I can see it in input , but at the output it would make more sense to me that it was a shunt topology, because Vo is equal to the voltage drop in the resistance RE.

Comment: "Vo is equal to the voltage drop in the resistance RE". Is it, really?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think, the shown block diagram can answer your question. The resistor RE provides current-controlled voltage feedback. The well-known formula for the resulting gain can, of course, be derived from the block diagram.

Please not, that I have assumed IC=IE and I have forgottem a "minus sign" in the last block (-RC). This inverting property for the emitter stage comes from the fact that Vout is referenced not to the positive power rail but to ground. More than that, the series resitsor RS (in your drawing) is not relevant for answering your question - therefore, the input voltage Vin is identical to the signal at the base node.

Comment: LvW- is your graph intuitive? Or systematic? Can you expand it to include the source, biasing and hie, hoe elements?
You can make the 'gm' '-gm' and add a '-1' block converting ic to ie before the 'Re' block in the feedback path to account for the inverting output sign.
The Rs element's contribution is small as long as the impedance at Vb is dominated by Rs as it should be in a good design. I like your anlysis.

Comment: Of course, it is "systematic". It visualizes the known formulas (with some simplifications like Ie=Ic). And it can be refined(extended to include neglected terms.